# Get a chat refresh constantly

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have a problem making my chat refresh constantly.

This is how I built it:

I save all messages in a MySQL database connected with PHP, loading the messages with PHP and post messages with PHP, I have jQuery making the message when clicked on submit send it to the chatbox.

[My website with the chat](http://swegre.se/)

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tzxmwxng/)

My problem is that when me and a friend chat, we have to refresh the site everytime someone writes something. I want to make the chatbox refresh constantly.
I have tried `$('#example').load(document.URL +  ' #example');` but it doesn't work, can someone please help me.

[HTML]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>ChatBox</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#content").load("ajaxload.php");

            $("a.btn").click(function(){
                $.post('ajaxPost.php', $('#userarea').serialize(), function(data){
                        $('#content').append('<p>'+data+'</p>');
                });
                return false;
            });

        });
    </script>
    <script src="chatbox.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chatbox.css" title="ChatBox" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="swegre">
        SWEGRE<span>&copy;</span>
    </h1>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h1>Leave a comment!</h1>
        <div id ="content">
            <p style="background-color: #b7b7b7">Admin: Here's our chatbox</p>
        </div>

        <div id="message">
            <form id="userarea">
            <textarea id="textareamsg" name="messages" rows="2" cols="30" required=""></textarea>
            <a href="#" class="btn">POST</a>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[CSS not important]
[jQuery]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $( "a.btn" ).click(function() {
                var textValue = $('textarea#textareamsg').val();
                if(textValue == "" || textValue == " " || textValue == "  " || textValue == "   "){
                    alert('You have to write something in the textarea to post a message');
                    return false;
                }else{
            $('#content').append("<p>You: " + textValue + "</p>");
            $('textarea#textareamsg').val('');
            }
            });
        });
```

[AjaxLoad.php]

```
<?php
//conection:
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","chat") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

//consultation:

$query = "SELECT * FROM messages" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));

//execute the query.

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

//display information:

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo '<p class="other">';
  echo $row ["message"] . '</p>';
}
?>
```

[AjaxPost]

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","chat") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

//consultation:

$query = "SELECT * FROM messages" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));

//execute the query.

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

//Code goes here

$message = $_POST['messages'];

mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO messages (message)
VALUES ('$message')");
?>
```

Comment: have you tried making an infinite loop of [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)? you can set it for as little as 1ms, although for chat I'd recommend probably 100 or 200ms.

Comment: Should I target the whole page or just the div? Because if I target the whole page it would be impossible to write something

Answer (score 2):

Use ajax to reload the chat div.

Steps

```
1. Make a chat div
2. Make  a ajax call every 10 sec
3. Design a  new page called chat.php
4. Update the chat data as per the db.
```

Moral: call ajax for every 10 sec

Comment: I don't know ajax, can you please show me a snippet of code so I can understand? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you could use microsoft technology: http://signalr.net/. The ideea is that it uses behind the scenes WebSockets. If can't use WebSockets it will fall back on using a "continuous" response.